# Subclass cant have parent exception of superclass

Tags: java, exception, overriding

I read that Subclass method cant have parent exception of superclass method. In exception hierarchy, ArithmeticException is derived from RuntimeException right? so the folowing code should give compile error. But its not giving..Can any one tell me why?

```
class Cafe
{
    void f() throws ArithmeticException{
        throw new ArithmeticException();
    }
}
class Coffee extends Cafe
{
    void f() throws RuntimeException{
        System.out.println("hi");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)throws ArithmeticException{
        Cafe c=new Cafe();
        c.f();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method **overriding** rules is for **checked exceptions only** and not `Runtime` exceptions only.The reason is that you can throw any `RuntimeException` anytime and compiler does not force you to handle it or declare the throws clause in your method signature.

Answer (score 0):

Because `RuntimeException` and its subclasses are unchecked exceptions. It is not necessary to mention them in a throws clause.